# @EJB(lookup) fails with org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I deployed an application on Websphere 8.5 and it gave the following exception:

```
[10/6/13 22:30:18:323 PDT] 000000be InjectionBind E   CWNEN0030E: The @EJB factory encountered a problem getting the object instance com.chander.test.web.managebean.Registration/staticDataService binding object.  The exception message was: Context: chander-4ae021bNode01Cell/nodes/chander-4ae021bNode01/servers/server1, name: com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService: First component in name com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService not found.
[10/6/13 22:30:18:417 PDT] 000000be annotation    E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper inject SRVE8060E: An unexpected exception occurred during resource injection.
                                 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: Unable to obtain an instance for com.chander.test.web.managebean.Registration/staticDataService: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: chander-4ae021bNode01Cell/nodes/chander-4ae021bNode01/servers/server1, name: com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService: First component in name com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1123)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejb.injection.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1101)
```

Following is the **Registration** class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name = "registration")
@SessionScoped
public class Registration implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Registration.class);

    private UserRegistrationForm form = new UserRegistrationForm();

    @EJB(lookup = "com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService")
    private StaticDataService staticDataService;

    public StaticDataService getStaticDataService() {
        return staticDataService;
    }

    public UserRegistrationForm getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(UserRegistrationForm form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    // navigation

    public String toFirstPage() {
        log.info("Registration First Page");

        return "REGISTRATION_FIRST_PAGE";
    }

    public String toSecondPage() {
        log.info("Registration Second Page");

        return "REGISTRATION_SECOND_PAGE";
    }

}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="chander.test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>oracle/chander_datasource</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.chander.test.dao.model.UserProfile</class>
        <class>com.chander.test.dao.model.CreditCard</class>
        <class>com.chander.test.dao.model.Address</class>
        <class>com.chander.test.dao.model.Country</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments"  value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService` is the name of your EJB class or interface. The `lookup` parameter of the `@EJB` annotation takes a JNDI path.

I do not know how Websphere 8 places EJBs in the JNDI context, but are you sure this is correct? Have you tried leaving out `lookup`, i.e.:

```
@EJB
private StaticDataService staticDataService;
```

Answer (score 0):

As your exception shows

```
com.chander.test.service.api.StaticDataService not found
```

StaticDataService  Which should be a interface and annotated with @Remote(javax.ejb.Remote) annotation. Also Add your ejb project in classpath of  web project. Now use @EJB to take the reference of interface.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html

```
@EJB
private StaticDataService staticDataService;
```

AS per my knowledge lookup use for a portable lookup string containing the JNDI name for the target EJB component.

You can refer

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21382740